# How to unsubscribe from all the Youtube channels at once?

Tags: javascript, automation, youtube

I have subscribed to more than 300 Youtube channels in past 10 years, and now I have to clean my Youtube, unsubscribing all one by one will take some time, is there a way to unsubscribe all the cannels at once?

Comment: I can't believe this question wasn't closed

Comment: Can someone please share the latest script as this is outdated now? Something that works in Feb 2023.

Comment: I have posted the updated script
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77182849/12019710

Comment: @JBis I'm trying it again lol

Comment: try out : youtubecleanse.com  [link](http://youtubecleanse.com)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Step 1: Go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels and scroll to the bottom of the page to populate all items to the screen.

Step 2: Right-click anywhere on the page and click "Inspect Element" (or just "Inspect"), then click "Console", then copy–paste the below script, then hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

Step 3:

```
var i = 0;

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 3000);

function myTimer () {

    var els = document.getElementById("grid-container").getElementsByClassName("ytd-expanded-shelf-contents-renderer");

    if (i < els.length) {

        els[i].querySelector("[aria-label^='Unsubscribe from']").click();

        setTimeout(function () {

            var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();

        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(function () {

            els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);

        }, 2000);

    }

    i++;

    console.log(i + " unsubscribed by YOGIE");

    console.log(els.length + " remaining");

}
```

Step 4: Sit back and watch the magic!

Enjoy!!

**NOTE:**  **If the script stops somewhere, please refresh the page and follow all four steps again.**

Comment: to run it faster, change second line as this var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

Comment: change from 3000 to 1000
and from 2000 to 500
It will work quickly as Jay said

Answer (score 26):

Updating the answer provided by everyone else (as the latest update did not work for me):

```js
var i = 0;
var count = document.querySelectorAll("ytd-channel-renderer:not(.ytd-item-section-renderer)").length;

myTimer();

function myTimer () { 
    if (count == 0) return;

    el = document.querySelector('.ytd-subscribe-button-renderer');
    el.click();

    setTimeout(function () {
        var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();
        i++;
        count--;

        console.log(i + " unsubscribed");
        console.log(count + " remaining");

        setTimeout(function () {
            el = document.querySelector("ytd-channel-renderer");
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

            myTimer();
        }, 250);
    }, 250);
}
```

For me this did the trick.

Comment: For me, too. And this snippet does not require manual listing to the end of the page.

Answer (score 9):

- Access the link : `https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels`
- Press **F12**
- Insert the code below in your console

```js
function youtubeUnsubscriber() {
    var count = document.querySelectorAll("ytd-channel-renderer:not(.ytd-item-section-renderer)").length;
    var randomDelay = 500;
    
    if(count == 0) return false;

    function unsubscribeVisible(randomDelay) {

        if (count == 0) {
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            setTimeout(function() {
                youtubeUnsubscriber();
            }, 10000)
        }

        unsubscribeButton = document.querySelector('.ytd-subscribe-button-renderer');
        unsubscribeButton.click();

        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("checkbox-enabled-confirm-button").click() // confirm button id has changed
            count--;
            console.log("Remaining: ", count);

            setTimeout(function () {
                unsubscribedElement = document.querySelector("ytd-channel-renderer");
                unsubscribedElement.parentNode.removeChild(unsubscribedElement);
                unsubscribeVisible(randomDelay)
            }, randomDelay);
        }, randomDelay);
    }

    unsubscribeVisible(randomDelay);
}

youtubeUnsubscriber();
```

### References

- https://github.com/vinnyfs89/youtube-unsubscriber

Answer (score 4):

Most effective values:

(copy all above this, including the last)

```
var i = 0;

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 200);

function myTimer () {

    var els = document.getElementById("grid-container").getElementsByClassName("ytd-expanded-shelf-contents-renderer");

    if (i < els.length) {

        els[i].querySelector('[aria-label="Unsubscribe from this channel."]').click();

        setTimeout(function () {

            var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();

        }, 500);

        setTimeout(function () {

            els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);

        }, 1000);
    }

    i++;

    console.log(i + " unsubscribed by YOGIE");
    console.log(els.length + " remaining");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a little addition to the best answer:
You can also use jscompress[dot]com to compress the script, then add **javascript:** at the beginning of the script, and add it to your bookmarks — you can run it from there — just in case you're not comfortable using console or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Updating [MordorSlave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10153598/mordorslave) answer. Just did it a moment ago.

Go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels and copy/paste the following in the console:

```
var i = 0;

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 200);

function myTimer() {

  var els = document.getElementById("contents").getElementsByClassName("ytd-subscribe-button-renderer");

  if (i < els.length) {

    els[i].querySelector('.ytd-subscribe-button-renderer').click();

    setTimeout(function() {

      var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {

      els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);

    }, 1000);
  }

  i++;

  console.log(i + " unsubscribed");
  console.log(els.length + " remaining");
}
```

Comment: All the scrip show me this error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')
    at myTimer (<anonymous>:12:57)
    at <anonymous>:29:1

Some script that work in 2024?

Answer (score 3):

this one works for me. Just refresh the page when all the rendered ones are finished and execute the script again. It's pretty fast.

```js
var i = 0;

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 500);

function myTimer () {

    var els = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(`ytd-channel-renderer`))

    if (i < els.length) {

        els[i].querySelector("[aria-label^='Unsubscribe from']").click();

        setTimeout(function () {

            var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button").querySelector("[aria-label^='Unsubscribe'").click();

        }, 300);

    }

    i++;

    console.log(i + " unsubscribed");

    console.log(els.length + " remaining");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/itsazzad/c1d86c5db86258ca129554a7b9ed92a7

Use the **DELAY** const wisely; consider your net speed.

```
// Go to the following link in your YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels
// Scroll the page all the way down until you reach the very last subscribed channel in your list
const DELAY = 100;
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
const list = document.querySelectorAll("#grid-container > ytd-channel-renderer");
for (const sub of list) {
  await delay(DELAY);
  sub.querySelector("#subscribe-button > ytd-subscribe-button-renderer > paper-button").click();
  await delay(DELAY);
  document.querySelector("#confirm-button > a").addEventListener('click', async event => {
    await delay(DELAY);
    console.log(sub.querySelector("#text").innerText);
    await delay(DELAY);
  });
  await delay(DELAY);
  document.querySelector("#confirm-button > a").click()
  await delay(DELAY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels.
2. Scroll all the way down till you see the last subscribed channel.
3. Open the javascript console, paste the following code and hit enter

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('paper-button > yt-formatted-string');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i += 1) {
    if (btns[i].innerText.toLowerCase() === 'subscribed') {
        btns[i].click();
        document.getElementById('confirm-button').click();
    }
}
```

**Note:** For me this method worked on Firefox. Chrome was giving warnings and the page became unresponsive. Worked on Oct 20th 2020 for an account with 956 subscribed channels.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Jani's answer, this one has a DOM progress counter. Absolutely no jQuery.

```js
(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var ytdElem = document.querySelector("ytd-page-manager ytd-browse.ytd-page-manager");
    ytdElem.innerHTML = '<div style="font: 11pt arial; background: yellow; color: white" id="ytdjsds"></div>' + ytdElem.innerHTML;
    var element = document.getElementById("ytdjsds");
    var count = document.querySelectorAll("ytd-channel-renderer:not(.ytd-item-section-renderer)").length;
    if (count == 0) {
        element.innerHTML = "No subscriptions were found on your account.";
        return;
    }
    element.innerHTML = `Deleting subscription 1 of ${count}`;
    function myTimer() {
        if (count == 0) {
            element.innerHTML = `Successfully deleted subscriptions`;
            return;
        }
        element.innerHTML = `Deleting subscription ${i + 1} of ${count}`;
        el = document.querySelector('.ytd-subscribe-button-renderer');
        el.click();
        document.getElementById("confirm-button").style.display = "none";
        setTimeout(function() {
            var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();
            i++;
            setTimeout(function() {
                el = document.querySelector("ytd-channel-renderer");
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                myTimer();
            }, 250);
        }, 250);
    }
    myTimer();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

To unsubscribe from all youtube channels

```
var i = 0;



function myTimer () {

    var els = document.getElementById("grid-container").getElementsByClassName("ytd-expanded-shelf-contents-renderer");

    if (i < els.length) {
        

        els[i].querySelector("[aria-label^='Unsubscribe from']").click();


            var unSubBtn = document.getElementById("confirm-button")
        setTimeout(() => {
             unSubBtn.children[0].children[0].click()
        }, 1000)
           
    setTimeout(() => myTimer(), 3000)

    }


    console.log(i + " unsubscribed by BIPPAN");
    i++;

}
myTimer()
```

Comment: You saved my life. This is perfectly working as of 11/10/2023. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Google changed some stuff up, so the script had to get modified, everything else remains the same.

```js
(async function iife() {
    // This is the time delay after which the "unsubscribe" button is "clicked"; Tweak to your liking!
    var UNSUBSCRIBE_DELAY_TIME = 2000;

    /**
     * Delay runner. Wraps `setTimeout` so it can be `await`ed on.
     * @param {Function} fn
     * @param {number} delay
     */
    var wait = (delay) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, delay);
        });

    // Get the channel list; this can be considered a row in the page.
    var channels = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(
            "ytd-subscription-notification-toggle-button-renderer-next > yt-button-shape > button"
        )
    );
    console.log(`${channels.length} channels found.`);

    var ctr = 0;
    for (const channel of channels) {
        try {
            // Get the subsribe button and trigger a "click"
            channel.click();

            await wait(100);

            document
                .querySelector("#items > ytd-menu-service-item-renderer:nth-child(4)")
                .click();

            await wait(800);

            document.querySelector("#confirm-button > yt-button-shape > button > yt-touch-feedback-shape").click();

            await wait(UNSUBSCRIBE_DELAY_TIME);

            console.log(`Unsubsribed ${ctr + 1}/${channels.length}`);
            ctr++;

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }

    }
})();
```

[credits](https://www.alphr.com/mass-unsubscribe-youtube/)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, wish I'd googled before rolling out my own. I had some fun with `async` and `await` with this. The screen does some ugly flashing while it's trying to unsubscribe stuff, but this does the job pretty well.

One prerequisite for this script to catch all channels in one go is to "exhaust" the scroller in the page ie., keep scrolling until you reach the end of your channel list. As others have stated, head on over to [YouTube Channels](https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels), open the developer console and paste the script that follows.

I've commented in relevant parts, in case this ends up becoming a learning experience for someone ;)

```
/** 
 * Youtube bulk unsubsribe fn.
 * Wrapping this in an IIFE for browser compatibility.
 */
(async function iife() {
  // This is the time delay after which the "unsubscribe" button is "clicked"; Tweak to your liking!
  var UNSUBSCRIBE_DELAY_TIME = 2000

/**
 * Delay runner. Wraps `setTimeout` so it can be `await`ed on. 
 * @param {Function} fn 
 * @param {number} delay 
 */
  var runAfterDelay = (fn, delay) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn()
      resolve()
    }, delay)
  })



  // Get the channel list; this can be considered a row in the page.
  var channels = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(`ytd-channel-renderer`))
  console.log(`${channels.length} channels found.`)

  var ctr = 0
  for (const channel of channels) {
    // Get the subsribe button and trigger a "click"
    channel.querySelector(`[aria-label^='Unsubscribe from']`).click()
    await runAfterDelay(() => {
      // Get the dialog container...
      document.getElementsByTagName(`yt-confirm-dialog-renderer`)[0]
        // and find the confirm button...
        .querySelector(`#confirm-button`)
        // and "trigger" the click!
        .click()
      console.log(`Unsubsribed ${ctr + 1}/${channels.length}`)
      ctr++
    }, UNSUBSCRIBE_DELAY_TIME)
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a working solution, the following script worked for me:

Go to https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager and run

```
$$('.yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded').forEach(function(el) { el.click(); $$('.overlay-confirmation-unsubscribe-button').forEach(function(el) { el.click(); }); console.log('Bye YouTube'); });
```

Ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/ad3jv5/mass_unsubscribe_script/

Answer (score 0):

My solution, most up to date i think, but things always changing...

```
var unsubBtns = document.querySelectorAll(' div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > ytd-subscribe-button-renderer:nth-child(1) > paper-button:nth-child(1)');

var i = 0; 

var interV = setInterval(function(){
   unsubBtns[i].click();
   i++;
   document.querySelector('yt-formatted-string.style-blue-text').click()
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

from this page https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels

```js
var list = $$('yt-formatted-string.ytd-subscribe-button-renderer')
function foo($$) {
  if (list.length === 0) return
  var el = list.pop()
  el.click()
  setTimeout(_=>{
    var cancel = $$('yt-formatted-string.yt-button-renderer')[1]
    cancel.click()
    console.log('done')
    setTimeout(_=>{foo($$)},100)
  }, 100)
}
foo($$)
```